# Synaptics Touchpad - low mouse polling rate

Tags: linux, linux-mint, xorg, laptop, touchpad

**My goal:**
I am trying to configure Linux Mint 21 Vanessa with the Cinnamon desktop environment (X11) on the HP EliteBook 850 G3.

**The problem:**
Everything seems to be working fine, except for the touchpad and the trackpoint. Both input devices kind of work, but the mouse polling rate is very low (on average around 30 Hz, sometimes drops to 20 Hz).
This makes moving the mouse cursor feel very sluggish.

**About the hardware:**
The laptop uses a Synaptics touchpad, which shows up as `SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad` when running `xinput --list`.

**What I have tried to fix it:**

- I plugged in an external USB mouse, which worked fine with a polling rate of about 100 Hz.
- I tried installing the older Synaptics driver (`xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`), instead of using `libinput`, but to no avail.
- I added `options usbhid mousepoll=2` to `/etc/modprobe.d/usbhid.conf` (lower number=less latency, higher number=more latency) and rebooted. Obviously that did not help since the touchpad can't even reach the default rate.
- I tested another distribution with KDE Plasma/Wayland, but that did not change the    situation.
- For testing purposes, I installed Windows 10. The polling rate was equally low without the proprietary Synaptics driver, but was much better when it was installed.

Does anyone know if it is possible to change the polling rate of a Synaptics Touchpad in GNU/Linux and if yes, how?
Thank you in advance!

P.S.: I am sorry for potential grammar mistakes since English is not my native language.